# wide to long amid merge

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to merge two dataset in the following way:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'company name':['A','B','C'],
               'analyst 1 name':['Tom','Mike',np.nan],
               'analyst 2 name':[np.nan,'Alice',np.nan],
               'analyst 3 name':['Jane','Steve','Alex']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'company name':['A','B','C'],
               'score 1':[3,5,np.nan],
               'score 2':[np.nan,1,np.nan],
               'score 3':[6,np.nan,11]})

df_desire=pd.DataFrame({'company name':['A','A','B','B','B','C'],
               'analyst':['Tom','Jane','Mike','Alice','Steve','Alex'],
               'score':[3,6,5,1,np.nan,11]})
```

Basically, df1 contains analyst name and df2 contains scores that analysts assign. I am trying to merge two into df_desire. The way to read two tables is: for company A, two person cover it, which are Tom and Jane, who assign 3 and 6 respectively. Noted that even though Steve covers company B but I deliberately assign the score to be NA for robustness purpose.

What I have done is :

```
pd.concat([df1.melt(id_vars='company name',value_vars=['analyst 1 name','analyst 2 name','analyst 3 name']),\
           df2.melt(id_vars='company name',value_vars=['score 1','score 2','score 3'])],axis=1)
```

I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df1.set_index("company name")
    .stack(dropna=False)
    .reset_index(name="name")
    .drop(columns="company name")
)
y = df2.set_index("company name").stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name="score")

print(
    pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)[["company name", "name", "score"]]
    .dropna(subset=["name", "score"], how="all")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Prints:

```
  company name   name  score
0            A    Tom    3.0
1            A   Jane    6.0
2            B   Mike    5.0
3            B  Alice    1.0
4            B  Steve    NaN
5            C   Alex   11.0
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thanks! Could you please elaborate a bit when to use "stack" with "dropna=False"  and "melt".

Comment: @Derek For simple cases like this I prefer `.stack()` over `.melt()` (melt gives you more control about identifier variables etc.). `dropna=False` in `.stack()` means I don't want to drop rows if there is `NaN` (like the case in your example).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) then [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to get expected dataframe

```
# 1. merge on company name
out = (df1.set_axis(df1.columns.str.extract('([^\d]+(?:\d+)?)', expand=False), axis=1)
          .merge(df2, on='company name', how='outer').reset_index())

# 2. convert wide to long
out = (pd.wide_to_long(out, stubnames=['analyst', 'score'], i=['index', 'company name'], j='id', sep=' ')
         .dropna(how='all').reset_index('company name').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  company name analyst  score
0            A     Tom    3.0
1            A    Jane    6.0
2            B    Mike    5.0
3            B   Alice    1.0
4            B   Steve    NaN
5            C    Alex   11.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you consider your tables to be a 3 dimensional `numpy.ndarray` then you can use some NumPy functions and reshaping here:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({
    'company name':['A','B','C'],
    'analyst 1 name':['Tom','Mike',np.nan],
    'analyst 2 name':[np.nan,'Alice',np.nan],
    'analyst 3 name':['Jane','Steve','Alex'],
})

df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'company name':['A','B','C'],
    'score 1':[3,5,np.nan],
    'score 2':[np.nan,1,np.nan],
    'score 3':[6,np.nan,11],
})

company_order = df1['company name'] # ensure all operations align correctly
frames = {'name': df1, 'score': df2}
frames = {
    name: d.set_index('company name').reindex(company_order)
    for name, d in frames.items()
}

arr = np.dstack([*frames.values()]) # join all dataframes into 3d array
n_companies, n_analysts, n_frames = arr.shape
result = (
    pd.DataFrame( # massage data into desired shape
        data=arr.reshape(-1, 2),
        index=company_order.repeat(n_analysts),
        columns=['name', 'score'],
    )
    .dropna(how='all')
)

print(result.reset_index())
#   company name   name score
# 0            A    Tom   3.0
# 1            A   Jane   6.0
# 2            B   Mike   5.0
# 3            B  Alice   1.0
# 4            B  Steve   NaN
# 5            C   Alex  11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

using `melt`, `concat` and a `duplicated` filter

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df1=pd.DataFrame({'company name':['A','B','C'],
               'analyst 1 name':['Tom','Mike',np.nan],
               'analyst 2 name':[np.nan,'Alice',np.nan],
               'analyst 3 name':['Jane','Steve','Alex']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'company name':['A','B','C'],
               'score 1':[3,5,np.nan],
               'score 2':[np.nan,1,np.nan],
               'score 3':[6,np.nan,11]})

# Code à mesurer
start_time = time.time()

df1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['company name'], 
              value_vars=df1.columns[1:], value_name='name')       
df2 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['company name'], 
              value_vars=df2.columns[1:], value_name='score')
       
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')[['company name', 'name',  'score']]

df3 = (( df3.loc[:,~df3.columns.duplicated()].copy() )
                         .dropna(subset=['company name', 'name'])
                         .reset_index(drop=True)
                       )

end_time = time.time()

# Calcul du temps d'exécution
temps = end_time - start_time
print(f"Temps d'exécution du script: {temps:.6f} secondes")
```

```
>>> df3
  company name   name  score
0            A    Tom    3.0
1            B   Mike    5.0
2            B  Alice    1.0
3            A   Jane    6.0
4            B  Steve    NaN
5            C   Alex   11.0
```

**Timing**

Efficiency rank measured using `time` module (I didn't include sammywemmy proposition because I had a bug):

```
# 1 - Cameron Ridell
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.001852 secondes

# 2 - Onyambu - Method 2
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.001866 secondes

# 3 - Onyambu - Method 1
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.004397 secondes

# 4 - Laurent B.
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.005277 secondes

# 5 - Andrej Kesely
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.007687 secondes

# 6 - PaulS
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.014832 secondes

# 7 - Corralien
# Temps d'exécution du script: 0.024980 secondes
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which first uses [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
ncol = 3 # number of cols of analysts/scores

dfs = [d.set_index('company name')
       .rename(columns=dict(zip(d.columns[-ncol:], range(ncol))))
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name=n)
       for d, n in zip([df1, df2], ['name', 'score'])]

pd.merge(*dfs, on=['company name', 'level_1'], how='left').drop(columns='level_1')
```

Output:

```
  company name   name  score
0            A    Tom    3.0
1            A   Jane    6.0
2            B   Mike    5.0
3            B  Alice    1.0
4            B  Steve    NaN
5            C   Alex   11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### method 1

```
(df1.set_axis(df2.columns, axis=1)
   .melt('company name', value_name='analyst').dropna()
   .merge(df2.melt('company name', value_name='score'))
   .drop(columns='variable'))

  company name analyst  score
0            A     Tom    3.0
1            B    Mike    5.0
2            B   Alice    1.0
3            A    Jane    6.0
4            B   Steve    NaN
5            C    Alex   11.0
```

#### method 2:

```
a = np.c_[np.tile(df1['company name'], df1.shape[1]-1), 
          df1.drop(columns='company name').to_numpy().flat, 
          df2.drop(columns='company name').to_numpy().flat]

(pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['company name', 'analyst', 'score'])
  .loc[lambda x: x['analyst'].notna()])

  company name analyst score
0            A     Tom   3.0
2            C    Jane   6.0
3            A    Mike   5.0
4            B   Alice   1.0
5            C   Steve   NaN
8            C    Alex  11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do a merge(on company name), and convert to long form with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1
.merge(df2, on='company name')
.pivot_longer(index='company name', 
              names_pattern={'analyst':'analyst',
                             'score':'score'},
              dropna=True
             )
)
  company name analyst  score
0            A     Tom    3.0
1            B    Mike    5.0
2            B   Alice    1.0
3            A    Jane    6.0
4            B   Steve    NaN
5            C    Alex   11.0
```

You can call dropna within `pivot_longer`, or exert more control and call dropna after.